# Lower bound on the rank of the elliptic curve $y^{2} = x^{3} + A x^{2} + B x$

Tags: number-theory

A recent [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33387/upper-bound-on-rank-of-elliptic-curve-y2-x3-ax2-bx?rq=1) on Math.SE discusses an upper bound on the rank in terms of the number of distinct prime divisors of $A$ and $B$, namely,
\begin{align}
r \leqslant \omega(A^{2} - 4 B) + \omega(B) - 1, 
\end{align}
where $\omega(k) = \sum_{p \mid k} 1$ is the number of distinct prime divisor (arithmetic) function. (A proof of this fact can be found within links posted in the comments and answers.)

Is there a similar, non-trivial lower bound? That is, are there (possibly arithmetic) functions of $A$ and $B$ which provide a lower bound for the rank of the elliptic curve in question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that such a lower bound is not known. Or if known, not effectively computable. Otherwise, I would think that more curves of high rank should be known than what is currently the case.